# Regex to ignore html tags when matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a java program and currently I am using regex to replace any terms found in a HTML document and this work fine.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(links);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
RegexText = m.replaceAll("ReplacementString");
```

However, words do not get matched should they be partially formatted with rich text tags. 
eg. **tes**ting

```
<b>tes</b>ting
```

The word "testing" does not get matched in this case because the "tes" is in bold text.

Is there any way to do a replace for a word broken by a tag like this. Also it is important I do not loose the rich text formatting on the word, so just stripping the tags without inserting them back in the correct position is not an option.

Comment: This is not a problem that can be solved with regex.  It will require MUCH more complex processing that understands exactly how text can be split up by inline tags.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't reliably match HTML to this extent with just regular expressions.  This is because HTML is a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) rather than a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) parseable using regular expressions.  The specific limitation is that a regular expression cannot associate the opening HTML tag to the closing tag, which it needs to do to perform the match while keeping the formatting intact.

Consider using an HTML parser instead - there are many options available for Java.